# How to execute commands from Haskell as root?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following Haskell function:

```
eraseFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
eraseFile basename = 
  do let cmd' = ">" 
         args' = ("/path/to/file/" ++ basename) :: String
     (exitcode', stdout', stderr') <- readProcessWithExitCode cmd' [args'] ""
     return ()
```

When I try to run this in a `stack ghci` repl, or from the main function, I get a `permission denied` error from the console. Normally, in a bash console, you could just run this command as `sudo`, but this doesn't seem to work when invoked from Haskell.

**Question:** How to execute system commands in Haskell as root?

Comment: have you tried to run `stack ghci` as root ?

Comment: Using sudo should work. The code above is wrong since `>` is not an executable name, that's shell syntax.

Comment: @TomaszLewowski: Yes, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `sudo /opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghc -e 'System.Process.readProcessWithExitCode "/usr/bin/env" [] "" >>= \(_, out, _) -> putStrLn out'` works fine and shows that `env` has been invoked as `root`. How did you actually check this code? Could you add all steps?

Comment: Changing the command to `truncate -s 0 filename` seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you can just run the entire stack/ghc under root, but I daresay that's a bad idea. Preferrably, I'd just invoke `sudo` as a process from within your program. The particular command – *emptying* a file, if I have understood that correctly? – is then easiest done with [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)):

```
  do let cmd' = "sudo" 
         args' = ["tee", "/path/to/file/" ++ basename :: String]
     (exitcode', stdout', stderr') <- readProcessWithExitCode cmd' args' ""
```

As Zeta remarks, `truncate --size 0` would probably be a cleaner command.

To get around password entering, you probably also want to make an exception in the [`sudoers` file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos#what-is-visudo). It's a hairy matter; of course the really best thing would be if you could avoid needing root permissions altogether.

Comment: "understoof"? Either way, while `tee` provides the functionality, `truncate --size 0` or even `cp /dev/null` might seem feasible. But that being said, I don't see any reason not to use `writeFile path ""` instead and propagate `sudo` "one level up". But that's just my 2¢.